# jQuery Ajax fails even with the HTTP 200 status

Tags: jquery, ajax

As the title sais, I have this Javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://192.168.20.249/test.brick",
      dataType: "json"
      }).done(function() { alert("success"); }).fail(function() { alert("error"); }).always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

My webserver sends these data:

```
200 OK
Date:  Tue, 12 Mar 2013 07:49:51 GMT

Server:  Hiawatha v8.8

Connection:  keep-alive

Transfer-Encoding:  chunked

Content-Type:  application/json

{"Test": "Hello"}
```

Any idea why jQuery thinks the request failed?

Comment: Are the calling server of ajax and the business logic execution server  on same IP?

Comment: I have the hiawatha webserver on a different computer than the jquery script. The hiawatha webserver handels the request over FastCGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your jquery script server and web server are different, it should be a cross-domain issue.

You should use **jsonp** for this communication.

Below is an example which can help you

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `error` callback to get som more info of what error jQuery sees?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.20.249/test.brick",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        ("error: " + textStatus); //Check all parameters in this callback
    },
    success: function(){
        alert("success"); 
    }
});
```

Edit: Cross domain ajax is not really as convenient as one would wish.