# Unable send the parameter string through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, web-services, xmlhttprequest

Hello i am trying to get response from a Web Service but when I send request parameters through  XMLHttpRequest.send(params) method, the request parameters doesn't gets sent.

Below is my code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
window.onload = function myFunc()
{
    var httpRes;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   
        httpRes=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    { 
        httpRes=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   
    httpRes.open("POST", "http://192.168.11.59:3333/Reports/GenerateMobReportJsonData", true);  
    var params = {'FromDate':'02/19/2013 17:30','ReportId':'1','LocationId':'1','ToDate':'02/19/2013 19:00','TeamId':'1'}
    httpRes.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    var jsonReq = JSON.stringify(params);
    //alert(jsonReq)
    httpRes.send(jsonReq);
}
</script>
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated...

Comment: are your jquery hosting server and the web service hosting server on same ip?

Comment: try httpRes.open("POST", "http://192.168.11.59:3333/Reports/GenerateMobReportJsonData", false);

Comment: @MarmiK: still problem remain as it is :-(

Comment: revise params
var params = {"'FromDate':'02/19/2013 17:30'","'ReportId':'1'","'LocationId':'1'","'ToDate':'02/19/2013 19:00'","'TeamId':'1'"}

try with this

Comment: @MarmiK: its giving syntax error in DW...

Comment: there you go. error is good, as you will come to know what is going on, what is the error?? what is DW??

The parameter 'abc':'123' will not work, make it string "abc:123", then second parameter..

Answer (score 0):

As you are using 'Application/Json' as your communication protocol and you jquery hosted server and web service server are different, there can be an issue of **CrossDomain** Request

Here you should use **Jsonp** as communication protocol.

Below is an example -

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Request between two different servers should go with jsonp protocol.

Also a similar kind of problem here -

[jQuery Ajax fails even with the HTTP 200 status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355902/jquery-ajax-fails-even-with-the-http-200-status/15356720#15356720)

Hope this help you.